# Subset of items which values sum contain in a given domain

Tags: python, subset, combinations

I have a collection of tuples :

```
items = (
    ('a', 7),
    ('b', 14),
    ('c', 21),
    ('d', 14),
    ('e', 7),
    ('v', 21),
    ('w', 14),
    ('z', 7) )
```

I want to find all possible subsets of above set of tuples that will be lower than first given number and greater by second given number. I have so far used a generator to produce a list of subsets made of values from tuples, but I would like to produce a subset of letters from above tuples which values or meeting the condition.

The code I have so far:

```
import itertools

items = [
    ('a', 7),
    ('b', 14),
    ('c', 21),
    ('d', 14),]


def subsets(lst, target1, target2, c = []):
    if sum(c) <= target1 and sum(c) >= target2:
        yield list(c)
    else:
        for i in lst:
            if sum(c+[i]) <= target1:
                yield list(subsets(lst, target1, target2, c+[i]))

a = list(subsets(list(j[1] for j in items), 29, 20))
print(a)
```

The output I have now

```
[7, 7, 7],
[7, 7, 14],
[7, 7, 14],
[7, 14],
[7, 21],
[7, 14],
[14, 7],
[14, 14],
[14, 14],
[21],
[14, 7],
[14, 14],
[14, 14]

The output I would like to have:

[a,a,a]
[a,a,b]
[a,a,d]
...
```

Also I would like to avoid repetition based on position of element, meaning ['d','b'] and ['b','d'] is the same and should only occur once in a result. For now I can see that the list of values I am producing is repeating this.

Comment: You are almost there and just need to add an additional return value/parameter to keep track of the indices. Is there a reason for using generators? Also, you are mixing recursion with for-loops - sticking to a single concept would simplify your code.

Comment: Btw, the solution (7, 7, 7, 7) is missing from your current output. Sum is 28 and 20 < 28 < 29.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to split the problem into two parts:

1. Finding the matching subsets of `items`.
2. Extracting the "labels" from the result (e.g. `"a"`, `"b"`).

```py
def format_results(subsets):
    """Extract labels from matching item subsets."""
    return [
        [item[0] for item in subset]
        for subset in subsets
    ]

def get_matching_subsets(items, lower, upper, current=None):
    """Fetch matching subsets of items."""
    current = current or []
    for item in items:
        next_ = current + [item]
        score = get_score(next_)
        if score <= upper:
            if score >= lower:
                yield next_
            yield from get_matching_subsets(items, lower, upper, current=next_)


def get_score(items):
    """Get the sum of item values."""
    return sum([item[1] for item in items])

ITEMS = [
    ("a", 7),
    ("b", 14),
    ("c", 21),
    ("d", 14),
]

LOWER = 20
UPPER = 29

RESULT = format_results(get_matching_subsets(ITEMS, LOWER, UPPER))
```

To modify this code to add the deduplication you require - you need only edit the `format_results` function:

```py
def format_results(subsets):
    """Extract labels from matching item subsets and deduplicate."""
    return {
        tuple(sorted([item[0] for item in subset]))
        for subset in subsets
    }
```

Note that with this (and your) approach, you need to be sure that all of the values are strictly greater than zero - or you will have infinite recursion!

As an aside, in your `subsets` function you have a default argument `c = []`. This is a common source of pain in Python, as it creates a global list. If you call the top-level recursion twice, the same list will be reused! That's why in my example I set the default to `None` (immutable), and then replace it with an empty list within the function.

Answer (score 0):

You've imported `itertools` but not used it. Here's a solution with [`combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

Pick combinations of increasing length, going from one to `max_elems`, which is set to the `upper_limit` divided by smallest number in values. (Assuming 0 and negative numbers are not present as values.)

```py
def subsets(lst, upper_limit , lower_limit):
    max_elems = upper_limit // min(n[1] for n in lst)
    for num_elems in range(1, max_elems+1):
        for combination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(lst, r=num_elems):
            total = sum(j[1] for j in combination)  # values, index 1
            if lower_limit <= total <= upper_limit:
                yield [j[0] for j in combination]  # letters, index 0

list(subsets(items, 29, 20))
```

Output:

```
[['c'],
 ['a', 'b'],
 ['a', 'c'],
 ['a', 'd'],
 ['b', 'b'],
 ['b', 'd'],
 ['d', 'd'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a'],
 ['a', 'a', 'b'],
 ['a', 'a', 'd'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
```

(Btw, ppl generally do `(lower_limit, upper_limit)` rather than the other way round; but I've left your function call as is.)

Another optimization in the inner loop:

```
for combination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(lst, r=num_elems):
    letters, numbers = zip(*combination)
    if lower_limit <= sum(numbers) <= upper_limit:
        yield letters  # or list(letters) if you don't want a tuple
```

---

To modify your *existing code* to include the letters, instead of doing `j[1] for j in items` use `j` directly so that it passes in the letter and the value. And only when you're checking the sum, use the value in `[1]`. It's important to do this *inside* your `subsets()` function because if you only do it with the results, then you need to go over the combinations *again*, since (7, 7, 7) can be ('a', 'a', 'a') or ('e', 'e', 'e') or all combinations of 'a', 'e' and 'z' since they are all 7. And then you'd need to filter out duplicates.

Comment: I think that using `combinations_with_replacement` in this way could miss out on valid combinations of more than `num_elems` items. For example `subsets([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)], 11, 10)` should include a list of 10 `"a"` values.

Comment: Good catch, I've modified the line which calculates `max_elems` when the rule of 7 does not apply. Uncomment that line to use it. And I'm assuming that zero (0) and negative numbers are not going to be present in the values.

Comment: @JackSmith Another edit: I've removed the whole thing about 7's and generalised `max_elems` to be based on the minimum value, which is what I meant by basing it on 7 but missed in my 'alternate' assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the resulting sums of each subset and then create a new list using the letters only.

```
import itertools

items = [
    ('a', 7),
    ('b', 14),
    ('c', 21),
    ('d', 14),]

def subsetnew(lstnew, target1, target2):
    lstofsubsets =[]
    # check that lst new is not blank
    if lstnew:
        itemsnew =[] # get new list of all combinations
        for i in range(len(lstnew)):
            for j in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(lstnew, i):
                itemsnew.append(j)
                
        lstofsubsets = [] # new subset with only those that match
        for i in itemsnew:
            chckthesum =0
            onlyletterslst = []
            for jy in i:
                 chckthesum += jy[1]
                 onlyletterslst.append(jy[0])
            if target2< chckthesum and chckthesum <target1: # check of the sum against target values
                lstofsubsets.append(onlyletterslst)
                
        lstofsubsets.sort() #here you can sort the list of subsets
    return lstofsubsets


a = subsetnew(items,29,20)
print(a)
```